# Update Dropdown with Express database results

Tags: jquery, node.js, sql-server, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-selectpicker

I am trying to update a selectpicker dropdown on page load based on values in SQL Server database using Bootstrap and Node.js but it's not working.  I am able to get SQL output through console.log inside express.js which means SQL connection is good but my dropdown is not populating.

BS Code

```
<body>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label action="/load"  for="selFlat">Select Flat:</label>
        <div class="row-fluid" novalidate>
            <select class="selectpicker form-element" id="selFlat" placeholder="Flat" name="selFlat" data-show-subtext="true" data-live-search="true">
                   <option>Option 1</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>

<script>
    $.noConflict();
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery.ajax({
            type:'GET',
            url:'/load',
            dataType:'json',
            success: function(data){
                jQuery('#selFlat').empty();
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
                    jQuery('#selFlat').append('<option>'+data[i].DocketNum+'</option>')
                }
            }
        });
      });
</script>
</body>
```

express.js

```
router.get('/load', function(req, res) {
    sql.connect({ connectionString }).then(() => {
        return sql.query ('select DISTINCT DocketNum from [dbo].[DocketData]')
    }).then(result => {
        console.log(result);
        res.render(path + '/UMMS_owner.html',{result:result});
        sql.close();
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
        sql.close();
    })  
});
```

Comment: Hi user12322515!  What specifically isn't working here, are you getting an error?  Is the dropdown not populating?  If we can add some more detail to this question I'm sure it'll help you get an better answer faster!

Comment: Drop down is not populating....something wrong....I am able to get SQL output through console.log inside express.js which means SQL connection is good but i guess some issue with express.js sending back SQL output to HTML and then updating the dropdown

Comment: Dear all, appreciate any help in this

Comment: Aspen, if you add an error handler to your ajax call, does it fire?  And if so, what's the error?

Comment: No errors are fired...what i receive in the ajjax response is "undefined". I guess data is sent back but some issue in how I am reading it back in the JQuery

Comment: I solved it finally....

        jQuery.ajax({
            type:'GET',
            url:'/load',
            success: function(data){
    var len=data.length;
                for (var i = 0; i <len; i++){
                    jQuery('#selFlat').append('<option>'+data[i].DocketNum+'</option>');
                }
   jQuery('#selFlat').selectpicker('refresh');
            }

Comment: express.js


router.get('/load', function(req, res) {

    const pool = new sql.ConnectionPool({ connectionString });
    var con = pool;
    con.connect(function(err) {
   if (err) throw err;
   con.query("select DocketNum from [umms].[dbo].[DocketData]", function (err, result, fields) {
    if (err) throw err;
     console.log(result.recordset);
     res.json(result.recordset);
      });
    });
});